# why UITabbarController is going too bottom

Tags: ios

[image: screenshot with menu and tabs]

I have Implemented top items a view with `UICollectionview` and `UIPagecontroller` to get android like pagetabs.

For each menu there is a container `ViewController` but in one of them need `UITabBarController`.

Why `UITabBarController` is going down.

I have tried moving menuVIew(Contacts,Recents,etc) up but still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For the top view, use **UISegmentedControl**, and make background color, same as border color.

For the tab bar, you mean that it is covered by home indicator?
[image: xCode Screenshot]

Turn on **Use Safe Area Layout Guides**, for this UITabController, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Use Safe Area Layout Guides is enabled still the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

```
let tabBar = UITabBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addTabbar()
}
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    addHeightConstraintToTabbar()
}

func addTabbar() -> Void {
    self.view.addSubview(tabBar)
    tabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tabBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tabBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    let item1 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.bookmarks, tag: 1)
    let item2 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.contacts, tag: 2)

    tabBar.items = [item1, item2]
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: tabBar)
}

func addHeightConstraintToTabbar() -> Void {
    let heightConstant:CGFloat = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + 49.0
    tabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant).isActive = true
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before for iPhone X. I found a weird solution of this as below:

Change the bottom constraint from TabBar to Safe Area not the Super view and change the constraint value to 1 as shown in the below image.

[image]

This works on both The normal devices and devices with notch display. Check out the screenshots :

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps you.